# vue changing selected option by js, using v-model

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How to control the selected value in a `v-model`ed `select` tag in vue.js?

I made a [jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/nuLy4svc/), this demo does not work, and expressed my question:

```
vm.$set('selected', '1') // not work!
vm.select('1') // not work!
```

I want to change `selected` to make the option to be changed when the js codes was executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try `vm.selected = 1` for example?

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Data-and-Methods

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/cmal/deLvksm4/ It does not work.

Comment: @cmal it works... if you open the console you see that `vm.$set('selected', '1')` is producing an error so the next line does not work. if you remove this line it works